# Database query to filter data inside an object array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nodes, mongoose-schema

I have bunch of documents in the following format in my mongodb, I am using moongoose as ORM.

Can some one help me make a query to get all the contents having the `name`=`abc` inside `data-items.content`

Document 1:

```
{
 "title": "Some title",
 "addresse": "data",
 "data-items": { 
 "content": [
   {
   "name": "abc",
   "age": "poster5.jpg"
   },
   {
    "name": "def",
    "age": "poster5.jpg"
   },
   {
    "name": "hij",
    "age": "poster5.jpg"
   }]
 }
}
```

Document 2:

```
{
"title": "another title",
"addresse": "data",
"data-items": {
  "content": [
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "age": "poster7.jpg"
    },
    {
      "name": "def",
      "age": "poster5.jpg"
    },
    {
      "name": "hij",
      "age": "poster5.jpg"
    }]
  }
 }
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to query an array of nested documents:

```
Model.find({"data-items.content.name": "abc"})
```

EDIT: to get only subdocuments matching your condition you can use below aggregation:

```
Model.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "data-items.content.name": "abc"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$data-items.content"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "data-items.content.name": "abc"
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$data-items.content"
        }
    }
])
```

[$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) will give you single document per `content` and [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) will promote it to the root level.

Comment: Yes, It works. Is there any way to just return matching objects rather than entire document?

Comment: @ArunBabuVijayanath modified my answer